# Reset Bluetooth audio codec after walking away and coming back

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth

When using Bluetooth headphones with A2DP, if I walk away from my computer to the edge of reception, I can hear that the codec switches down to a lower bitrate to try to accommodate the situation.  When I come back, the low quality audio remains until I power off my headphones, turn them back on, and pair them again.

Is there any sort of easier/faster way to reset the codec without having to reset the headphones?

Intel Bluetooth on a Lenovo T480 running Windows 10 x64, and a Shure BT1 earphones adapter.

Comment: See if in an elevated PowerShell this has the same effect as re-pairing: `Get-Service -DisplayName *Bluetooth* | Restart-Service`, or `Get-Service -DisplayName *Bluetooth* | Restart-Service -Force`. If that works, it can be packaged inside a batch file on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Bluetooth services might have the same effect as redoing the
pairing, regarding the playback quality on the computer, as the Bluetooth
software should then forget the need for lower bitrate.

Use the following command in elevated mode:

```
powershell "Get-Service -DisplayName *Bluetooth* | Restart-Service -Force"
```

If this works, you can put it in a desktop shortcut for easy use.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to turn the headphones off - just disconnect and reconnect. Similar to harrymc's answer, you could also try to restart the bluetooth services - experiment around by reproducing the problem then opening the services (run `services.msc` at a command prompt or Run box) and try it with the bluetooth entries (for ex, bluetooth support service). If it fixes it, find the service name and make a batch file to run `net restart <service>` (without the arrow characters). Then you could keep it on the desktop to double click to restart the bluetooth service, potentially re-connecting it to your headphones.